# ¿Como incluir un buscador web sin que google rechaze la conexión?

Tags: html

El día de hoy me gustaría saber si es posible añadir un navegador web de google.
Lo que estoy probando es lo siguiente, pero google rechaza la conexión:

```
<iframe src="https://google.com" width="192" weight="108">
```

Imagen del resultado:
[image: Google Bloqueó la conexión]
Espero que alguien que me puedan ayudar.
Y gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Creo que no es posible... google restringe mucho su seguridad... Por cierto, no es `height`?

Comment: Creo que esto es lo que quieres lograr: https://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Google-Search-Bar-to-Your-Website Saludos.

Comment: Yo creo que tu página puede redirigir y cargar. Lo que no va a funcionar es embeber eso en un iframe. google tiene en los headers un XFrame SAMEORIGIN, entonces tu sitio pepito.com no cumple y el navegador no lo va a pintar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8700636/13419694